# How can I select maximum index with equal column values using idxmax() function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
   pcn_no   treatment   score
1   101 3000    0.005804
2   101 5000    0.005804
3   101 8000    0.005804
5   101 12000   0.005804
8   101 25000   0.005804
12  101 50000   0.005804
4   101 10000   0.014521
6   101 15000   0.014521
7   101 20000   0.014521
9   101 30000   0.014521
10  101 35000   0.014521
11  101 40000   0.014521
```

Here I want to select max line as 40,000 but using below code I am getting 10,000 as the max line:
x = 'score'
df_all[x + '_max_line'] = df_all.loc[(df_all.groupby('pcn_no')[x].idxmax(),'treatment')]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to using `idxmax()`, which gives the index of the first occurrence of the maximum score. In your `dataframe`, because the maximum score repeats, you're not necessarily getting the largest 'treatment' value for that score.

```
df_all = df_all.sort_values(by=['score', 'treatment'], ascending=[False, False])
df_all['score_max_line'] = df_all.groupby('pcn_no')['treatment'].transform('first')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns the first match of the highest score, you can simply reverse the column, by using `[::-1]`, like so:

```py
...
x = 'score' 
df_all[x + '_max_line'] = df_all.loc[(df_all.groupby('pcn_no')[x][::-1].idxmax(),'treatment')]
```